# Bit Hack in C Cannot Understand

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I was asked this question in an interview and still cannot figure out what it does. Can someone explain what it does and how it does it?

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & (T)~(T)0/3);                           // temp
v = (v & (T)~(T)0/15*3) + ((v >> 2) & (T)~(T)0/15*3);      // temp
v = (v + (v >> 4)) & (T)~(T)0/255*15;                      // temp
c = (T)(v * ((T)~(T)0/255)) >> (sizeof(T) - 1) * CHAR_BIT; // count
```

Comment: What is the value of T, and the datatypes of T, V and C

Comment: It can be any type. Think of it like a template in c++.

Comment: Was the interview for the position of [INTERCAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL) programmer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is explained here:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel

**Counting bits set, in parallel**

> A generalization of the best bit counting method to integers of bit-widths upto 128 (parameterized by type T) is this:

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & (T)~(T)0/3);                           // temp
v = (v & (T)~(T)0/15*3) + ((v >> 2) & (T)~(T)0/15*3);      // temp
v = (v + (v >> 4)) & (T)~(T)0/255*15;                      // temp
c = (T)(v * ((T)~(T)0/255)) >> (sizeof(T) - 1) * CHAR_BIT; // count
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast!  How did you find this?

Comment: Just beat me to it! :D +1 for the fast find :)

Comment: @templatetypedef this page is THE page for C bit hacks, so I just went to check if it was already here.

Comment: @dtb in the page there is the explanation for the `32`-bit version, this version is a generalization and it is very similar to the `32`-bit version

Comment: @MatthewHoggan check the page for the explanation, you can find another explanation in this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815165/how-to-implement-bitcount-using-only-bitwise-operators

Comment: @ouah Thanks that second link explained it better. I googled the code, but did not understand the explaination.

Comment: It is basically the Hamming weight algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight