# Number of flags that are in two variables in enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Letter
{
    NONE  = 0,
    A = 1, 
    B = 2, 
    C = 4,
    A_B = A | B,
    A_C = A | C,
    B_C = B | C,
    ALL = A | B | C
}
```

And I have the following piece of code:

```
Letter first = Letter.A_B;
Letter second = Letter.B_C;
```

How to get the number of flags that is in `first` variable but also in `second` variable?

The result I would like to have:

```
Letter first = Letter.A_B;
Letter second = Letter.B_C;
int numberOfSameFlags = ...; // should return 1 in this example

Letter first = Letter.A_B;
Letter second = Letter.ALL;
int numberOfSameFlags = ...; // should return 2 in this example
```

I tried bitwise operations but I don't think I can get this value from that.

Comment: If you want to use *only* bitwise operations, you can do it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815165/how-to-implement-bitcount-using-only-bitwise-operators) way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can AND the flags together and then count the number of set bits (this is known as the ["Hamming Weight"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of an integer).

One way you can count the set bits (there are many, this is one I grabbed off the net):

```
public static int HammingWeight(int i)
{
     i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
     i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
     return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

So for your problem:

```
Letter first = Letter.A_B;
Letter second = Letter.B_C;
Console.WriteLine(HammingWeight((int)first & (int)second));
```

And:

```
Letter first = Letter.A_B;
Letter second = Letter.ALL;
Console.WriteLine(HammingWeight((int)first & (int)second));
```

If you want to know how that particular implementation works, [see here](https://yesteapea.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/counting-the-number-of-set-bits-in-an-integer/).

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer is through the BitArray class

```
int f = Convert.ToInt32(first);
int s = Convert.ToInt32(second);
BitArray bit = new BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(f & s));
Console.WriteLine(bit.Cast<bool>().Count(x => x));
```